How to restrict access to my API written in DRF?
I have an email form on my website to contact me. It's implemented using Django Rest Framework. It only accepts POST requests.
@api_view(['POST'])
def send_email(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.data.get("name")
        email = request.data.get("email")
        subject = request.data.get("subject")
        message = request.data.get('message')

        message_con = 'Message: ' + message + '\nEmail: ' + email + '\nName of the sender: ' + name
        print("sent via POST")
        try:
            send_mail(subject, message_con, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, ['someemail@gmail.com'])
            return Response({"message": _("Email Successfully sent!")})
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return Response({"error": e}, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
            
    return Response({"error": _("Method Not Allowed.")}, status=status.HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)

How do I restrict access to its API on my web site for other users? Is it possible to accept requests only from my form?

This is the purpuse of CSRF protection, for usage in DRF consult https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/ajax-csrf-cors/#csrf-protection

@MatijaSirk Oh, Thank you. It was already there so i have nothing to worry about
